# How to delete file called "-C"

Tags: bash, files, solaris

I need to delete the following file which I managed to create with bunzip2:

```
 -rw-r--r--   1 beginner group    67493376 Feb 17 17:30 -C
```

The following don't work

- `rm -rf '-C'`
- `rm -rf "-C"`

My OS is solaris.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `--` to distinguish between options which start from `-` and filename or prepend file with `./`. The safest is to use both:

```
rm -- './-C'
```