# how to delete file that start with "-"

Tags: shell, rm, options

I try to delete this file on my solaris machine

```
rm "-Insi"

rm: illegal option -- I
rm: illegal option -- n
rm: illegal option -- s
```

I also try this

```
 rm "\-Insi"

 -Insi: No such file or directory


 rm '\-Insi'

 -Insi: No such file or directory
```

so what other option do I have?

Comment: Can you post the output of the ls here?

Comment: My immediate reaction was that we _must_ have covered this before, given how often people ask it.  According to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185520/ we've had it at least twice before; once even specifically talking about Solaris.  ☺

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
rm -- -Insi
```

or:

```
rm ./-Insi
```

Answer (score 2):

`man rm` (at least on Ubuntu ... my Solaris box is not plugged in) tells me this:

> ```
>    To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo',
> use one of these commands:
>
>           rm -- -foo
>
>           rm ./-foo
> ```

Comment: the `--` characters are the general "stop parsing options" demarker